# Is there a survey on whether people have gained or lost weight as a consequence of lockdown?

Tags: coronavirus, biostatistics

I am not sure if this is the right forum for asking such a question. Moderators can of course close it if it isn't and please migrate it to relevant site.

Is there a survey/study that statistically checks whether people have gained or lost weight as a consequence of lockdown?

Of course, it would be a complicated as there would be a need for number of controls such as age, usual changes in lifestyle of subjects (independent of lockdown), etc.

Comment: Weight is not usually something surveyed. The female part of the population will not answer, half of the men don't know nor care and a good proportion of the rest will answer with a wrong number. Weight is something you really need to measure. I expect that what you are after will come out of controlled studies that measure weight routinely and need to account for the confounding effect of the pandemic.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have edited the question accordingly.